# Native SQL result as a hibernate POJO

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I have a subquery

```
select * 
  from Employee 
 where employeeId in (
              select employeeId 
                from dept as x 
               where x.name ='Dept1' 
                     and x.category ='category1' 
                     and x.employeeId IN (
                                  select employeeId 
                                    from dept as x 
                                   where x.name ='Dept2' 
                                         and x.category ='category2'))
```

I want to select the return list as employee POJO objects.

I am using hibernate.

Thanks

Comment: yw. what's the question? And where is your closing parentheses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the below code worked for me.

```
session.createSQLQuery(query).
      addEntity("employee",Employee.class).
      setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY).
      list();
```

Thanks